# Vuex getter returns undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I have a vue app using vex to store site wide data I get the user info and put it into the state on the before create life cycle method like so:

```
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    store,
    beforeCreate(){
        store.dispatch('currentUser');
    }
});
```

In my user module I have a getter that gets the name of the user like below:

```
const getters = {
    getName(state){
        return state.user.name;
    }
};
```

In my components I am trying to access the getter to display the name of the user in the component. When I look into the Vue Chrome dev tools the getter is not undefined, but when I console log the getter results like so it says undefined.

```
mounted(){
    console.log(store.getters.getName);
},
```

It seems like the component is loading before the state is loaded. I am getting the user info using axios. I am really confused on how to solve this since I can not call the action to get the user data any sooner that I know of.

If in my getter method I do:

```
state.user
```

I get this:

```
{ "id": 1, "name": "Test" }
```

But when I try to get name I get undefined

Here is the store:

```
import axios from "axios/index";

const state = {
    user: {},
};

const mutations = {
    FETCH_USER(state,user){
        state.user = user;
    },
    UPDATE_AVATAR(state,avatar){
        state.user.avatar = avatar;
    }
};

const getters = {
    getName(state){
      return state.user.name
    },
    avatar(state){
        return state.user.avatar;
    },
    userSocialNetworks(state){
        //return state.user.social_networks
    },
    schoolName(state){
        return state.user.school
    },
    schoolAbout(state){
        return state.user.school.about
    },
    schoolAddress(state){
        return state.user.school.address
    }
};

const actions = {
    currentUser: ({commit}) => {
        axios.get('/api/user').then(response => {
            commit('FETCH_USER', response.data);
        });

    }
}

export default {
    state,
    getters,
    actions,
    mutations

}


 {"user":{"user":{"name":"Test","email":"test@test.edu","avatar":"http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/xxxx=300","city":null,"state":null,"zip":null,"address":null,"lat":null,"long":null,"role":"school","school":{"id":1,"about":null,"header":null,"name":"Test","user_id":1,"created_at":"2018-06-06 19:48:16","updated_at":"2018-06-06 19:48:16"},"following":[],"followers":[],"social_networks":[{"id":4,"user_id":1,"social_network_id":1,"network_url":"test.com/k","created_at":"2018-06-06 23:11:09","updated_at":"2018-06-06 23:15:19"},{"id":5,"user_id":1,"social_network_id":2,"network_url":"test.com/k","created_at":"2018-06-06 23:15:19","updated_at":"2018-06-06 23:15:19"},{"id":6,"user_id":1,"social_network_id":5,"network_url":"test.com/k","created_at":"2018-06-06 23:16:15","updated_at":"2018-06-06 23:16:15"}]}},"socialNetowrks":{"available_networks":[{"id":1,"network_name":"Facebook","created_at":null,"updated_at":null},{"id":2,"network_name":"Instagram","created_at":null,"updated_at":null},{"id":5,"network_name":"Twitter","created_at":null,"updated_at":null}]}}
```

Comment: you need to use `this.$store.getters.getName` within components

Comment: What is the difference

Comment: The difference is one is undefined and the other isn't

Comment: @Derek I get this error using store that way Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined"

Comment: That means `state.user` is undefined

Comment: @Derek when I just do state.user it returns { "id": 1, "name": "Test" } but name makes it undefined

Comment: Did you `Vue.use(vuex)` ?

Comment: @Derek yes I did. I can return the object that contains the name fine with no errors but when I try to get name from it thats when it gives me errors

Comment: That type of error is indicative of not doing `vue.use(vuex);` what does your Vue DevTools Vuex tab display?

Comment: @Derek It displays the whole user object with its name and relations

Comment: Show me what your store looks like, edit the original post

Comment: @Derek It is in the question

Comment: I meant the store code, not the stores state data

Comment: @Derek the user module is in the question

Comment: How are you exporting/importing your store? it should be something like `export default new Vuex.Store({});` and `import store from './store'`

Comment: @Derek I am importing it like you have it and all the modules are imported in a index.js file in the store directory. IN the index file I use this export default new Vuex.Store

Comment: Try using `mounted()` instead of `beforeCreate()`

Comment: @Derek I tried all of the lifecycle method and the same error persists

Comment: I have the exact same problem, did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 3):

You are facing two big issues here:

1. You should not update the object directly in the vuex store or you'll lose reactivity

So make sure you declare all of your state correctly and you assign to objects instead of overwriting them

```js
import assignDeep from 'assign-deep'; //Since you have nested structure you will need this

const state = {
    user: {
       name: '',
       school: {
          about: '',
          address: '',
       },
       // Make sure all properties are defined
    },

};

const mutations = {
    FETCH_USER(state,user){
        assignDeep(state.user, user);
    },
    UPDATE_AVATAR(state,avatar){
        state.user.avatar = avatar;
    }
};
```

2. You are trying to access a property that is asynchronously defined on the state and using it synchronously (before it exists)

First make use of the `mapGetters` utility of vuex for easier usage

```js
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex';
//... In component definition
computed: {
  ...mapGetters({name: 'getName'})
}
```

Since this is a vue computed property, your component will rerender when it gets defined and everything should display properly you just need to make sure you handle the case when it's empty and maybe display a loading screen until it is

For example

```html
<template>
  <div v-if="!name" class="loading"></div>
  <div v-else>{{name}}</div>
<template>
```

You're also free to just wait for the property to update

Do not use it in the mounted hook as it will still be the default value there

Instead use a [watcher or a computed property](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html) depending on your needs

```js
watch: {
  name: {
    handler(name, oldName) {
      if (name) {
        //Do something
      }
    },
    immediate: true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, methods hasn't been initialized yet in `beforeCreate` hook. The easiest way around this it to use the `created` hook instead:

```
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    store,
    created(){
        store.dispatch('currentUser'); // considering you have properly imported and exported vuex
    }
});
```

In your component

```
import {mapGetters} from 'vuex';

export default {
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters(['getName'])
  }
}
```

Comment: Even this does not work The schoolName method can return the object but not the name attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring the specific variables in the store to properly initialize the data:

```
const state = {
    user: {
        name: '',
        avatar: '',
        school: '',
        ...
    },
};
```

I was having the same issue you described until I did this.

Answer (score -5):

You can try this:

```
mounted() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(store.getters.getName);
  }, 400);
},
```

Comment: setTimeout is really a bad practice .-)